# Java regexp: splitting on "/" that is not at the beginning of a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to split `a/bc/de/f` as `[a, bc, de, f]` but `/a/bc/de/f` as `[/a, bc, de, f]`.

Is there a way to split on `/` which is not at the beginning of the string? (I'm having a bad Regexp day.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably just to split `s.substring(1)` on `/`, and then prepend `s.charAt(0)` to the first result.

Other than that, since the split regex is not anchored, it would be challenging to do.  You'd want to split on "something that isn't the start of the line, followed by a slash" - i.e. `[^^ ]/` - but this would mean that the character preceding the slash was stripped out too.  In order to do this you'd need negative look-behind, but I don't think that syntax is supported in the String.split regexes.

Edit: According to the [Pattern javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) it seems that Java **does support negative lookbehind**, and the following regex may do the job:

```
s.split("(?<!^)/");
```

A quick test indicates that this does indeed do what you want.

Comment: As I explained (and as MByD demonstrated) elsewhere, lookbehind isn't really necessary in the `split()` regex; lookahead works just as well.

Answer (score 10):

`(?!^)/` seems to work:

```
public class Funclass{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s = "/firstWithSlash/second/third/forth/fifth/";
        String[] ss = s.split("(?!^)/");
        for (String s_ : ss)
            System.out.println(s_);

    }
}
```

output:

```
/firstWithSlash
second
third
forth
fifth
```

As **@user unknown** commented, this seems to be a wrong expression, it should be `(?<!^)/` to indicate negative lookbehind.

Comment: @f1sh: It's negative lookahead.

Comment: Can you tell, where to find an explanation, how this works; how to read this? `^` is the beginning of the string, but `?!`?

Comment: @user unknown - Actually, no, I had a mistake and the correct syntax is `(?<!^)/` I wasn't noticed since it worked...

Comment: MByD: Lookahead or lookbehind, it doesn't matter.  The regex engine doesn't have to consume any characters to match `^`, so it doesn't matter which way it's "looking" when it does it. @user: [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should get you started.

Comment: Well, I learned from the comments more than the question and answer. great!

Comment: `As @user unknown commented` ... too much honor! No, I simply searched for an explanation, which was provided by the link, given by @Alan Moore, about lookbehind, lookaround and friends. :)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just add a check at the beginning to see if there's a slash in the beginning?

```
if( str.charAt(0) == '/' ) {
    arr = str.substring(1).split( "/" );
    arr[0] = "/"+arr[0];
} else
    arr = str.split( "/" );
```

Or a little simpler:

```
arr = str.charAt(0) + str.substring(1).split( "/" );
```

If the first is a slash, it'll just slap on a slash at the beginning of the first token. If there's only one character in the first token (that doesn't begin with a slash), then the first array element is the empty string and it'll still work.